# How to query lat lon from pandas Series to get expected value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, geospatial

As you can see in the picture below, i cannot pass lat lon value thought the series to get time series data (date, value). How can i get it using pandas in python?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vaDB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you describe a little more for what you want ?

```
df.reset_index() # this could allow your to access lat and lon as normal column
```

Not sure if this is what you are asking for, please explain more